# Get data from dynamic html page with java

Tags: java, html

I wanna get data from [Live Cyber Atack](https://threatmap.checkpoint.com/ThreatPortal/livemap.html). I want to take the data include: Time, Attack, Attacking Country, Target Country. I want to take this dynamic data. After analyzing. I am using Java. How can i do?

```
<div ng-repeat="attack in latestAttacks" class="attackRow" "="">
            <div class="timeCol" inline-animation="{ properties: { opacity : 1 }, duration: 500, easing:'swing'}" style="opacity: 0.0254519;">
                <p>
                    14:40:22
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="attackCol" inline-animation="{ properties: { opacity : 1 }, duration: 500, easing:'swing'}" style="opacity: 0.0254519;">
                <p class="attackContainer">
                    infecting website.cb
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sourceCol" inline-animation="{ properties: { opacity : 1 }, duration: 500, easing:'swing'}" style="opacity: 0.0254519;">
                <p>
                    China
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="destCol" inline-animation="{ properties: { opacity : 1 }, duration: 500, easing:'swing'}" style="opacity: 0.0254519;">
                <p>
                    India
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I did not write the above code. I wanted to show the location of the data that I want to take just.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is to get the data like this website does through WebSocket. So first you need a WebSocket client, here I use the reference implementation of [JSR 356 - Java API for WebSocket](http://java.net/projects/websocket-spec) which is [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/).

Assuming that you use maven, here are the dependencies to add to your project for a WebSocket client:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

The data that you will receive is in JSON format, so you will need a parser that you will have to add to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is how the code looks like:

```
final ClientEndpointConfig cec = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build();
URI uri = new URI(
    "wss://threatmap.checkpoint.com/ThreatPortal/websocket" +
    "?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0" +
    "&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.2.5-javascript" +
    "&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket" +
    "&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true" +
    "&Content-Type=application/json" +
    "&X-atmo-protocol=true"
);
ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
try (Session session = client.connectToServer(new Endpoint() {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
        session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                // The data is of type "number|JSON Object"
                // so we remove everything before the JSON Object
                message = message.substring(message.indexOf('|') + 1);
                if (!message.startsWith("{")) {
                    // Not a JSON Object so we skip it
                    return;
                }
                // Parse the JSON Object
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
                if (jsonObject.has("attackname")) {
                    System.out.printf(
                        "Time: %tT Attack: %-40s Attacking Country: %-20s Target Country: %-20s%n",
                        Calendar.getInstance(), jsonObject.getString("attackname"),
                        new Locale("", jsonObject.getString("sourcecountry")).getDisplayName(),
                        new Locale("", jsonObject.getString("destinationcountry")).getDisplayName()
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, cec, uri)) {
    CountDownLatch messageLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    // Wait forever
    messageLatch.await();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Time: 14:53:06 Attack: Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Sohanad.B        Attacking Country: United States        Target Country: Panama              
Time: 14:53:06 Attack: Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Sohanad.B        Attacking Country: United States        Target Country: Panama              
Time: 14:53:06 Attack: Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Sohanad.B        Attacking Country: United States        Target Country: Panama              
Time: 14:53:06 Attack: Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Sohanad.B        Attacking Country: United States        Target Country: Panama              
Time: 14:53:07 Attack: Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Sohanad.B        Attacking Country: United States        Target Country: Panama              
Time: 14:53:07 Attack: Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Sohanad.B        Attacking Country: United States        Target Country: Panama              
Time: 14:53:07 Attack: Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Sohanad.B        Attacking Country: United States        Target Country: Panama              
Time: 14:53:07 Attack: REP.huvcru                               Attacking Country: France               Target Country: Panama              
Time: 14:53:08 Attack: REP.huvcru                               Attacking Country: France               Target Country: Panama
```

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I did not edit the data in this site. Can you help me? http://hp.ipviking.com/

Comment: it's another problem so please post a new question for that, we cannot mix problems, thx in advance

Comment: Sadly, I have to wait. Thank you again.

Comment: Why do you have to wait?

Comment: I do what I want. Thank you so much again. Two questions can be asked here in one day. I learned through this. :)